# Same nfs mount options, different output

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, rhel5

I have 2 OEL5.5(RHEL5.5) servers.
I'm trying to figure out why when I run `mount` command I get different outputs.

Server1 has the following line in `/etc/fstab/`

```
10.11.0.61:/vol/exports/      /exports     nfs     _netdev,rw,bg,hard,nointr,tcp,vers=3,timeo=600,actimeo=0,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,async 1 2
```

Server2 has the following line in `/etc/fstab/`

```
10.11.0.61:/vol/exports/      /exports     nfs     _netdev,rw,bg,hard,nointr,tcp,vers=3,timeo=600,actimeo=0,rsize=32768,wsize=32768     1 2
```

When I run mount on Server1 I see

> 10.11.0.61:/vol/exports/ on /exports type nfs (rw,bg,addr=10.11.0.61)

When I run mount on Server2 I see

> 10.11.0.61:/vol/exports/ on /exports type nfs (rw,bg,hard,nointr,tcp,nfsvers=3,timeo=600,actimeo=0,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,addr=10.11.0.61)

Why does Server2 show more parameters? Does it mean it's mounted differently?

Comment: Hm.  Can you also check with `cat /proc/mounts`?  Sometimes the kernel's idea of mount options differs from the one reported by `mount`.

Comment: server1 shows `cat /proc/mounts`
10.11.0.61:/vol/exports /exports nfs rw,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,addr=10.11.0.61 0 0
server2 shows `cat /proc/mounts`
10.11.0.61:/vol/exports /exports nfs rw,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,acregmin=0,acregmax=0,acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,addr=10.11.0.61 0 0

Comment: The rsize and wsize are incorrect on server1

Comment: This is a good question. Have you tried mounting it from the command line? Maybe try it with different mount options too.